# python __init__ argument becomes a tuple

Tags: python, init

Code:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, aa  ):
        print('aa='+str(aa)+' of type '+str(type(aa)))
        self.aa = aa,
        print('self.aa='+str(self.aa)+' of type '+str(type(self.aa)))

DEBUG = MyClass(aa = 'DEBUG')
```

Output:

```
aa=DEBUG of type <type 'str'>
self.aa=('DEBUG',) of type <type 'tuple'>
```

Why does `self.aa` become a tuple and not a string?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Beause of the comma here:

```
self.aa = aa,
```

This is the [syntax for a tuple containing one element](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TupleSyntax) .